# trigger popup or div id on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help to trigger popup on page load.

Currently the popup will open when i click "hello" link.

**Expected result:**

Popup should open without clicking the hyperlink or popup on  **document ready**

HTML

```
<a class="button2" href="#popup1">hello</a>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
    <div class="contentSpec">
        <h2>Would you like to visit</h2>
        <h1>someURL</h1>
    </div>
    <a class="close" href="#"></a>
    <div class="content">

        <div class="box">
        <a class="button" href="#popup1">YES</a>
        <a class="button1" href="#popup1">NO</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-size: cover;
}


.box {
  margin: 6% auto 3% auto;
  padding: 35px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button, .button1 {
    padding: 1.5% 4% 1.5% 4%;
    margin: 2%!important;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    font: normal 1em;
    text-align: center;
    -o-text-overflow: clip;
    text-overflow: clip;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.button{
    border: 2px solid rgb(30,205,151);
    color: rgb(30, 205, 151);
}
.button1{
    border: 2px solid orange;
    color: orange;
}
.button:hover {
    background: rgb(30,205,151);
    color:#fff;
}
.button1:hover {
    background: orange;
    color:#fff;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 5% 2%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border:10px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  border:3px solid rgba(55, 174, 204, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin:0;
}
.popup h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 2%;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius:50px;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:before {
  content: "×";
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  text-align:center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.product{
color:#777;
}
.contentSpec{
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button2").trigger('click');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3errLzvs/4/)

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.location.hash = "#popup1";
});
```

This is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3errLzvs/9/)

Comment: yes, this answer is more precise. thanks. 
i need one more help. 
 on click of YES it should navigate to google.com, if NO facebook.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa that is just because jsfiddle uses frames and those sites will not open in frames. This should work fine on your own site. You could also use `window.open('https://google.com','_blank');` on click events for your buttons too.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code on `document.ready()`:

```
window.location="#popup1";
```

[Here is your **updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3errLzvs/4/)

[Here is **CodePen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjyXPN) since JSFiddle is messing up and not updating properly

---

### Full Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$(".button2").trigger('click');
  
  window.location="#popup1";
});

$(".button").click(function(){
  window.location="http://www.google.com/";
});
$(".button1").click(function(){
  window.location="http://www.facebook.com/";
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-size: cover;
}


.box {
  margin: 6% auto 3% auto;
  padding: 35px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button, .button1 {
 padding: 1.5% 4% 1.5% 4%;
 margin: 2%!important;
 text-decoration:none;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
 border-radius: 40px;
 font: normal 1em;
 text-align: center;
 -o-text-overflow: clip;
 text-overflow: clip;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0);
 -o-transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0);
 transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0), border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.button{
 border: 2px solid rgb(30,205,151);
 color: rgb(30, 205, 151);
}
.button1{
 border: 2px solid orange;
 color: orange;
}
.button:hover {
 background: rgb(30,205,151);
 color:#fff;
}
.button1:hover {
 background: orange;
 color:#fff;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 5% 2%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border:10px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  border:3px solid rgba(55, 174, 204, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin:0;
}
.popup h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 2%;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius:50px;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:before {
  content: "×";
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  text-align:center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.product{
color:#777;
}
.contentSpec{
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button2" href="#popup1">hello</a>


<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <div class="contentSpec">
   <h2>Would you like to visit</h2>
   <h1>someURL</h1>
  </div>
  <a class="close" href="#"></a>
  <div class="content">
   
   <div class="box">
   <a class="button" href="#popup1">YES</a>
   <a class="button1" href="#popup1">NO</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AmitSingh Did you click 'Run' to run the JSFiddle?

Comment: thank you its working, can you please help me. on YES it should navigate to google.com, if NO facebook.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa I [updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGEwBg) the code on codepen. Its not gonna work in the demo (due to restrictions) but try it in your real code and let me know.

Comment: @AmitSingh Sry for the code not working, JSFiddle was messing up.

Comment: @Ahs N i need one more help. on click of YES it should navigate to google.com, if NO facebook

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa Check again. I tested the codes locally (on chrome), it works.

Comment: i checked once again, it is not working. yes button is not going to google

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button2")[0].click();
});
```

Because you need to fire native DOM API click method. [0] returns the DOM node, this is equivalent to get(0). Otherwise, if you trigger click() event on jQuery object, the native method is specifically discarded.

Have a look at this **[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174134/triggering-click-event-on-anchor-tag-doesnt-works)**