# Triggering click event on anchor tag doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-trigger

I just ran into **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173463/trigger-popup-or-div-id-on-document-ready)**

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3errLzvs/13/)**

Triggering `click` event on anchor tag is not working here.

```
<a class="button2" href="#popup1">hello</a>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="contentSpec">
      <h2>Would you like to visit</h2>
      <h1>someURL</h1>
    </div>
    <a class="close" href="#"></a>
    <div class="content">

      <div class="box">
        <a class="button" href="#popup1">YES</a>
        <a class="button1" href="#popup1">NO</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button2").trigger('click');
});
```

My question, is why the trigger event is not working in this case?

Comment: Try `$(".button2").click()`

Comment: @AdamAzad Tried, still not working.

Comment: What doesn't work. If I click on it then it displays Would you like to display some URL.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to call native DOM `click()` method in order to fire default clicking anchor behaviour, jQuery specifically [excludes it on anchor](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c9935b6d2db9e1be4bed12f7419e98cdca45763e/src/event.js#L515):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button2")[0].click();
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Works fine but why did I need to use the index(0) here. I mean even if I change the class to and ID it doesn't work?

Comment: @AmitSingh Like said, you need to fire native DOM API click method. `[0]` returns the DOM node, this is equivalent to `get(0)`. Otherwise, if you trigger `click()` event on jQuery object, the native method is specifically discarded, i posted ref in jq source

Comment: All that said, if you want to support older browsers and avoid some issue because of browser not firing native click method beghaviour or not supporting `:target` CSS pseudo class, better is to toggle a class, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/3errLzvs/22/

Comment: Explicit exclusion! - you just saved my day!

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
$(".button2").get(0).click();
```

The `get(0)` will return the first DOM object instead of the jquery object, and `click()` will be triggered.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3errLzvs/18/)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>As you don't have any `.click()` event bound on it, it never fires it.</strike>

You need to fire the DOM `click` event with `.click()` instead of `.trigger(e)` of jQuery method and this should only work on dom nodes. Which you can achieve by introducing the index `[0]` or with jQuery's method `.get(0)`.

Instead try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button2")[0].click();
  // or $(".button2").get(0).click();
});
```

and if this is the case then you can do this with javascript only:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e){
   document.querySelector('.button2').click();
}, false);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3errLzvs/16/. I can see clicked in console log, but popup still doesn't opens up.

Comment: @AmitSingh what popup? you don't have any code there for popup. Instead you just have to write it up.

Comment: Okay! i get it now then you need to use A.wolff's answer.