# Anchor tag click event is not working in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a use-case to add a dynamic anchor tag and make a click event after it. The code is working fine in all the browsers except safari.

```
var link = document.createElement('a'); 
link.href="https://www.google.com";
link.target = '_blank';
link.id = "asst-link";
document.body.appendChild(link); 
document.getElementById('asst-link').click();
```

any advice?

Comment: When is this code called?

Comment: Ask your question like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174134/triggering-click-event-on-anchor-tag-doesnt-work

Comment: Does it work, by any chance, if you remove `link.target = '_blank';`? That would indicate that this probably gets eaten by the popup blocker.

Comment: If you're trying to open a new tab/window, just use `window.open(yourUrlHere)` instead of going through all the trouble of dynamically creating an `a` element and programmatically clicking on it - which is an action that may be blocked by the browser as the user didn't instigate it.

Comment: window.open is not working in Safari

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cbroe in the comments.

I had the same problem, removed the `target="_blank"` attribute and it worked.

Comment: This seems to be a good answer, but it would be best converted to a community wiki since the information is from another user.

Comment: How do I do that @joanis?

Comment: You can click on the edit button, then there should be a check mark box you can click labeled Community Wiki.