# can't get the child of a div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to when i click on the div 'nav-item' the child tag a get clicked , i have try some way but it's not working for me

PS : i don't want to wrap the parent div with tag a

```
<div class="nav-item" data-nav-item="1">
  <div class="item-parent">
    <a href="https://mystore-men.com">MEN</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav-item" data-nav-item="2">
  <div class="item-parent">
    <a href="https://mystore-women.com">Women</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery :

```
$('.nav-item').click(function () {
  $(this).children('a').click();  
});
```

can anyone help please ?

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday with a different user. Rather than switching user, you should focus on improving your question.

Comment: Is it possible you can change the HTML? You could set the `a` element to be the outer container (ie. the `.nav-item`) and then you'll get this behaviour without any relying on any brittle JS logic for you navigation, which in itself will have accessibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `find` jquery method since `find` method returns all the descendant elements like child, grandchild and so on.

Here's the jquery code,

```js
$('.nav-item').click(function () {
  $(this).find('a')[0].click();
});
```

The `find` method returns all the descendant `a` elements. I'm selecting the first one `[0]` and triggering the click event.

Comment: The key to this answer is not `.find` or `[0]` it's that it uses the DOM `.click()` event instead of the jquery `.click()` event.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34174253/2181514 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to solve your request only using the css padding ?

```css
.nav {display: flex;}
.item-parent a {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-item" data-nav-item="1">
    <div class="item-parent">
      <a href="https://mystore-men.com">MEN</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-item" data-nav-item="2">
    <div class="item-parent">
      <a href="https://mystore-women.com">Women</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the clickable area of your `<a>` element to cover the entire parent element by using absolute positioning.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() !== "A") {
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(e.target.href);
});
```

```css
.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav-item .item-parent {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav-item a::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-item" data-nav-item="1">
  <div class="item-parent">
    <a href="men">MEN</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav-item" data-nav-item="2">
  <div class="item-parent">
    <a href="women">Women</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what he wants is to trigger the `a` tag so that it will go the link definded in the `a` tag

if so you can get the href property of the child `a` tag and redirect the window to that link on `.nav-item` click

if you want to open the link in a new tab you can use this line  `window.open(link, '_blank');` instead of `window.location.href = link;`

```js
$(".nav-item").click(function(){
  var link  = $(this).find("a").prop("href");
  window.location.href = link;
});
```

```css
.nav-item{
  background-color: yellow;
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav-item" data-nav-item="1">
  <div class="item-parent">
    <a href="https://mystore-men.com">MEN</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav-item" data-nav-item="2">
  <div class="item-parent">
    <a href="https://mystore-women.com">Women</a>
  </div>
</div>
```